# A C# function to check a date from day month year

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, datetime

I have three strings/ints which are day, month, and year. Is there any way of checking if they're in a valid DateTime format? I am using ASP.NET.

When a user registers, he enters a month, day and year.

I used to convert the three variables to a string and tryParse to check if it's legal, but the only problem is running the same project on a different machine because some different machines use different date formats.

Comment: [DateTime.TryParse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx) or [DateTime.TryParseExact()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx).

Comment: TryParse has an overload that lets you specify the culture (and the culture defines the date format).

Comment: On those machines, you set the Locale when doing the parse.

Comment: Consider using DateTime.ParseExact, you can set the date format as a parameter.

Comment: If you `TryParse` use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` as format provider to ensure the machine's "own" date format is disregarded.

Answer (score 9):

how about this:

```
    private bool IsValidDate(int year, int month, int day)
    {
        if (year < DateTime.MinValue.Year || year > DateTime.MaxValue.Year)
            return false;

        if (month < 1 || month > 12)
            return false;

        return day > 0 && day <= DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);
    }
```

Comment: This is much better than using a try catch exception.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have *day*, *month* and *year* as three separate ints, you can use directly [one of DateTime's constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcfzdy4x.aspx), instead of putting them into a string and re-parsing it as a DateTime.

```
DateTime mydate;
myDate = new DateTime(year, month, day);
```

this will throw a `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` if the date is invalid, so you should wrap this in a try/catch block and use a `catch(ArgumentOutOfRangeException e)` block to manage the logic when your date does not have a valid format.